# no ros workspace after rebooting

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros doesn't keep the workspace in "fuerte" after rebooting my computer, I have to keep telling ros where the workspace is after booting the computer. Can anyone help assess what the problem is or how to solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63443/no-ros-workspace-after-rebooting/) by [mv](https://answers.ros.org/users/4968/mv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-24**:
Did you source the setup.bash in the workspace in your .bashrc?

**Comment by [mv](https://answers.ros.org/users/4968/mv/) on 2013-05-28**:
I am not sure what you mean, I just followed the tutorial from ros and it says to re-source with: source ~/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash .... was there an extra step I had to do?

**Comment by [mv](https://answers.ros.org/users/4968/mv/) on 2013-05-28**:
Thank you joq!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you run `source ~/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash`, it only sets things up in the current shell (terminal window).  To get things to work every time you start a shell (terminal window), you need to add the line

```
source ~/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash
```

to the file `.bashrc` in your home directory.  This file is sourced every time you start an (interactive) shell.

---

Originally posted by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) with karma: 1263 on 2013-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2013-05-28**:
This is what joq asked in the comment to the question.  I'm assuming that your answer was "no".

**Comment by [mv](https://answers.ros.org/users/4968/mv/) on 2013-05-28**:
Thanks guys, sorry but I am still new with linux and ros. But thank you so much for the help!